# Implementing bootstrap alert components

Tags: bootstrap-4

```
<% if(success && success.length) {%>
    <div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
        <%= success %>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
          </button>
    </div>
    <% } %>

        <% if(error && error.length) {%>
            <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
                <%= error %>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
            </div>
            <% } %>
```

In the first image, I am trying to implement bootstrap alert function in my project but the close button is not similar refer to pictures for more reference.

[image: It is a image from bootstrap alert function]

[image: from my local system trying to implement bootstrap alert function]

Comment: It seems you have some sort of `CSS` rules that override `Bootstrap`'s styling. Please consider adding your `CSS` code to the question so we can investigate.

Answer (score 0):

Just replace your button with this

```
 <button type="button" class="close" style="position: absolute; top: 0;right: 0;padding: .75rem 1.25rem;color: inherit;" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
```

Comment: I didn't add CSS, i am only using bootstrap.